# Scilab/Matlab binary search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab, scilab

I'm trying to solve a problem
"Construct an algorithm that, for a non-randomly ordered one-dimensional array, determines the multiplicity of occurrences of a given value. Note: use a binary search algorithm for this purpose"

I came up with the idea of searching for the first appearance of the given value, and then using the while loop I will check how many times it appeared.

I wrote some code that works but I have the following problems with it

```
function tab=tablica(N)
    tab=floor(N*rand(1,N))
endfunction


function tab=tablicaP(N)
    tab=gsort(tablica(N),'g','i')
endfunction

function wynik=szukam(T,X)         
    P=1
    K=length(T)
    s=0
    i=0
    while P<=K 
        s=floor((P+K)/2)
        if T(s) == X then
            //wynik = s
            if T(s) == 1 then
               // wynik = s
                break
             else
             if T(s-1) == X then
                 K = s -1
             else
                // wynik = s
                 break
             end
          end
        elseif T(s) < X then
            P = s+1
        else
            K=s-1        
            end
    end

while T(s) == X  do
    i=i+1
     s=s+1
   end


wynik = i            
endfunction
```

But while trying to search for 8 i got this error, and honestly i dont know what to do with this

```
at line    28 of function szukam ( C:\Users\Tragu\Desktop\algorytm11.sce line 42 )

Invalid index.
```

Also sometimes while trying to reach first index in table i get this error

````
 tab2  = 

   0.   4.   5.   5.   5.   6.   6.   6.   7.   8.   8.   8.   9.   9.   10.   11.   11.   12.   18.   18.

--> szukam(tab2,8)
 ans  =

   3.

--> szukam(tab2,0)
at line    14 of function szukam ( C:\Users\Tragu\Desktop\algorytm11.sce line 28 )

Invalid index.```

So my main issue is somewhat related to first and last index of table.
Any tips or how to deal with that?
````

Comment: Matlab uses 1-based array indexing. Most example code for binary search you find on the internet is probably written in a language that uses 0-based array indexing. You might need to add some `+1` or `-1` operations in there (especially when calculating halfway points) to adjust for that. Stop it in the debugger where it raises that error and see what the bad index value actually was; that should give you a lead.

Comment: `Matlab uses 1-based array indexing.` : Scilab as well. Indices start at 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use successive binary search to find both start and end of your sequence. Here your last loop falls back to O(n) complexity. Here is a working code (BTW your code fails because you do not take into account limiting cases, below `s==1` and `e==n`):

```
a=[0 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 8 8 8 9 9 10 11];
n=length(a);
k=[1 n];
v=8;

while k(2) >= k(1)
    s=floor(mean(k));
    if (s==1 || a(s-1)<v) && a(s)==v
        break
    elseif a(s)<v
        k(1)=s+1;
    else
        k(2)=s-1;
    end
end

if k(2) >= k(1)
    k=[s n];
    while k(2) >= k(1)
        e=floor(mean(k));
        if (e==n || a(e+1)>v) && a(e)==v
            break
        elseif a(e)<=v
            k(1)=e+1;
        else
            k(2)=e-1;
        end  
    end
end

disp(s,e)

   10.

   12.
```

If the value is not found `k(1) > k(2)`. You can find recursive implementations there: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-first-and-last-positions-of-an-element-in-a-sorted-array/